# Laravel race conditions on user registration

Tags: php, sql, laravel

My app's user table cannot use a unique column. So I've done this with the Laravel validation.
The problem with this is that the "race condition" problem sometimes occurs when registering a user.

I have tried several ways to fix the problem

I used firstOrCreate and now firstOrNew but the problem didn't fix.

Although I have checked the record for non-duplicate records in the previous lines, I also checked the record's duplication status when adding records to the database, but the problem was not fixed.

```
<?php
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'phone' => ['required', 'digits:11', 'unique:users,phone,null,id,deleted_at,NULL', phoneRegExValidateRule()],
            // other fields ...
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = User::firstOrNew([
            'phone' => $data['phone'],
        ]);

        if ($user->exists) {
            flash()->error('error', 'duplicate user');

            return redirect()->route('home');
        } else {
            $user->fill([
                // fields ...
            ]);

            $user->save();
        }



        $user->meta()->create([
            // fields ...
        ]);

        return $user;
    }
}
```

Since the "race condition" problem occurs at the last moment and when the record is inserted into the database, it seems that I should use table locking. But I don't know what happens to other parts of the program that use this table when locked.
I also don't know how to write this code

Comment: Your table cannot use a unique key because...?

Comment: @Pablo Because no field in the table can be unique. Even the mobile number field can be a duplicate if the deleted_at is filled.

Comment: it will be easier for you to deal with the possible duplicate record than deal with the race condition

Comment: [mpyw/laravel-retry-on-duplicate-key: Automatically retry non-atomic upsert operation when unique key constraints are violated.](https://github.com/mpyw/laravel-retry-on-duplicate-key)

Answer (score 0):

The User Unique Validation need to be done from DB and cant be done through laravel.

Comment: Because I have used soft delete it is not possible to use a unique field in the table.
What about locking the table? Can't solve the problem this way?